# Limit visibility of Site Content and structure, customize Sitemanager.aspx?

Tags: 2010, wiki, content-deployment

In my current scenario the users would like to move wiki pages from one folder to another. 
The only way to do this is using the site content and structure and it works fine.

However, the site content and structure shows many stuff, like style library, master pages, etc, etc.

I would like the user to be able to use the site content and structure but only the wiki page library should be visible to them.

Is it possible?

Comment: Even though the other libraries are displayed, people who dont have rights, wont be able to move or delete anything from those libraries. Do you still want to remove them from their view?

Comment: Yes, just to simplify the view for them, is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this on MSDN.

With out of the box functionality you can trim out objects from site content and structure by breaking inheritance and removing permissions from the content you do not want users to see.  However by removing the users permissions, they would not be able to access the content outside of site content and structure either.  If moving wiki content around in this method is require, I would recommend leaving this task to the site administrator.
For more information on permission inheritance in SharePoint 2010, please refer to the following documentation:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262778.aspx